# How to use IF...ELSE sql statement with multiple selects?

Tags: sql, t-sql

Simple academic project. Simple procedure. If there is something already in Payments table - then take debt value from that table, if there are no values - take it from Tariff table. But why such conidtion doesn't work?

```
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.GetDebt
    (
    @LoanId int
    )
AS

    IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT top 1 * FROM Payment WHERE LoanId = @LoanId) 
    BEGIN
        SELECT (TotalLoan + ( ( TotalLoan / 100 ) * Interest))  as Debt FROM Loan L, Tariff T
        WHERE L.TariffIf = L.TariffId
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        SELECT MIN(Debt) as Debt FROM Loan L 
        RIGHT OUTER JOIN Payment P -- Joins are cool.
        ON L.LoanId = P.LoanId
        WHERE P.LoanId = @LoanId 
    END
```

Comment: You forgot to add ON clause in right join.

Comment: Also, you forgot to never use `right join`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If/Else is almost always the entirely wrong approach for sql code. It's hard to give you an exact example without knowing more about your tables, but you really want something more like this:

```
SELECT COALESCE(P.Debt, TotalLoan + ( ( TotalLoan / 100 ) * Interest))  as Debt
FROM Loan L
LEFT JOIN Tariff T ON T.LoanID = L.LoanID
LEFT JOIN (SELECT LoanID, Min(Debt) As Debt FROM Payment GROUP BY LoanID) P
WHERE L.LoanID = @LoanID
```

No If/Else required.

Comment: As for description of COALESCE, I'll analyze how it works and will use it. Looking better, then IF..ELSE statements.

Answer (score 4):

use `BEGIN` and `END` around your statements like so:

```
IF (SELECT count(*) FROM Payment WHERE LoanId = @LoanId) = 0 
BEGIN

    SELECT (TotalLoan + ( ( TotalLoan / 100 ) * Interest))  as Debt FROM Loan L 
    RIGHT OUTER JOIN Tariff -- TODO: Add correct ON clause here
    WHERE L.LoanId = @LoanId

END
ELSE
BEGIN
    SELECT MIN(Debt) as Debt FROM Loan L 
    RIGHT OUTER JOIN Payment P -- Joins are cool.
    ON L.LoanId = P.LoanId
    WHERE P.LoanId = @LoanId 
END
```

Also note that you are missing an `on` clause for your `right outer joins` which will cause errors.

Also it might be more efficient to change

```
IF (SELECT count(*) FROM Payment WHERE LoanId = @LoanId) = 0
```

to

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Payment WHERE LoanId = @LoanId)
```

The keyword being "might"

Comment: This isn't working. I tried this, before posting this question. Still error at WHERE.

Comment: Dude, I copied your sql without really looking it at. Your sql is not working to begin with because you are missing the `on` and its expressions after your `right outer join`

Comment: Oh... That's sad that I didn't notice this.